# Counter to List

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a counter like this :

```
counter = Counter(['a','a','b','b','b','c'])
```

which gives this object :

```
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1})
```

and from that I want to creat a list such as :

```
list[0] = 'b'
list[1] = 'a'
list[2] = 'c'
```

any idea to do that the simpliest and fastest way possible please ? thanks

Comment: What order do you want for the elements of the list? What have you tried?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter.most_common`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) (which returns a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least):

```
>>> counter.most_common()
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]

>>> [key for key, _ in counter.most_common()]
['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest (IMO) method as told by falsetru

```
sorted(counter, key=counter.get, reverse=True)
```

The above would sort the counter `dict` based on the values of the keys (`.get()`) & return a reversed `list`.

Comment: Thanks Ashish that is what I am looking for except that your code gives me the ascending order, what can i change so i can get the descending order please

Comment: Or, you could do `reversed(sorted(counter.keys(), key=lambda x: counter[x])`

Comment: Can be shortened as `sorted(counter, key=counter.get, reverse=True)`; `sorted` receive any iterable. (Iterating a dictionary yields keys)

Comment: @falsetru Thanks, didn't know `.get()` could be utilized like that.

Comment: I didn't say it is the fastest. And this is not the shortest one. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can cast it to a list, but it will not keep the order you want since dictionaries are unsorted:

```
list1 = list(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to skip the steps you can type.

```
list(set(['a','a','b','b','b','c']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
from collections import Counter
import operator

counter = Counter(['a','a','b','b','b','c'])
print [k for k,v in sorted(counter.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]
# ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

Or, better still:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(['a','a','b','b','b','c'])
print [k for k,v in counter.most_common()]
```